# imageview onClick

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

i want to make a game that when the user clicks all image view the layout would intent to another level.So far i can't find the right code.Would you please help me?

here's some of my codes.

```
ChairA1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ChairA1.setImageResource(R.drawable.chair);

        }
    });

     ChairA2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 ChairA2.setImageResource(R.drawable.chair);

            }
        });

     ChairA3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 ChairA3.setImageResource(R.drawable.chair);

            }
        });

     ChairA4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 ChairA4.setImageResource(R.drawable.chair);

            }
        });



 //here i where i would put the codes
```

Answer (score 3):

Start new activity when click on image

```
ChairA1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             ChairA1.setImageResource(R.drawable.chair);
             Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this,new.class);
             startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: i know that...my point is when All the imageviews are Change/Clicked (R.drawable.chair), the layout would intent...

Comment: mean Do you want to change images ?

Comment: i cant chat...i dont have 20 reputations

Comment: can any one help me on this?